# CentOS: command not found inside shell file

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, centos

I am running on CentOS 6 and using Apache2.

If I run the following from the command line, it works perfectly

```
wp --help
```

However, when I try to run 'wp' command from a shell file that is called by a php script, I get an **command not found error**.

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $PATH
whereis wp
wp --help
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
system("./test.sh >> test.log 2>&1");
?>
```

the output will be (**test.log**)

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin/wp
wp: /usr/local/bin/wp
./test.sh: line 4: wp: command not found
```

I tried every combination of permissions but I still get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try saving full path to `wp` into some variable, then use it in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

WP=`whereis wp | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
$WP --help
```

Comment: thanks, is there any explanation why it didn't work? there is a reference to the WP folder in PATH

Comment: @NizarBlond from which user this script executes? (`echo $USER`) What are permissions for this user on wp?